# SQL Server DateTime Accept NULL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've tried to make my code as compact as possible.

Using Microsoft SQL Server, .NET 2.0

I have a date field in my database which accepts null values

```
LeaseExpiry(datetime, null)
```

I grab the value of the the textbox and convert it to datetime.

```
DateTime leaseExpiry = Convert.ToDateTime(tbLeaseExpiry.Text);

INSERT_record(leaseExpiry);
```

The problem I'm having is if the form is submitted and the textbox is empty. I get this error back:

> *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

How do I set my code up so that if the textbox is empty, the row is created in the database with `NULL`?

I've tried initializing my variable to NULL but get an error in Visual Studio

```
DateTime leaseExpiry = null;
```

> *Cannot convert null to 'System.DateTime' because it is a non-nullable value type.*

Here's the Data Access Layer if that helps

```
public string INSERT_record(DateTime leaseExpiry)
{
     //Connect to the database and insert a new record 
     string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connname].ConnectionString;

     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnn))
     {
        string SQL = string.Empty;
        SQL = "INSERT INTO [" + dbname + "].[dbo].[" + tblAllProperties + "] ([LeaseExpiry]) VALUES (@leaseExpiry);

         using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, connection))
         {
                command.Parameters.Add("@leaseExpiry", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                command.Parameters["@leaseExpiry"].Value = leaseExpiry;
         }

         try
         {
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return "Success";
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
                return ex.Message;
         }
     }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It should be spelled `leaseExpiry` (not `leaseExpirey`) - you had both version in your code, which is really confusing. I fixed it to be `Expiry` all the time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Indeed, `DateTime` cannot be `null`. But: `DateTime?` can be. Note also that on a parameter, `null` means "don't send"; you would need:

```
public string INSERT_record(DateTime? leaseExpirey)
{
    // ...
    command.Parameters.Add("@leaseExpirey", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    command.Parameters["@leaseExpirey"].Value =
                ((object)leaseExpirey) ?? DBNull.Value;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using a nullable DateTime and TryParse()

```
DateTime? leaseExpirey = null;
DateTime d;
if(DateTime.TryParse(tbLeaseExpiry.Text, out d))
{
    leaseExpirey = d;
}

INSERT_record(leaseExpirey);
```

Comment: Thank you i've used this too.

Answer (score 3):

You could make `leaseExpirey` a nullable `DateTime` - i.e. `DateTime? leaseExpirey`

Then you can say:

```
DateTime? leaseExpirey;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbLeaseExpiry.Text.Trim()))
    leaseExpirey = Convert.ToDateTime(tbLeaseExpiry.Text);

INSERT_record(leaseExpirey);
```

You'd also need to change `INSERT_record` to accept a `DateTime?` parameter instead of `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DateTime.MinValue`, since DateTime is never `null`.